# Juniper ex4200 neighbour discovery rate limit (IPv6)

Tags: juniper-junos, juniper-ex

We have a few Juniper EX4200 and they are working in layer2 , Is there anyway to rate limit the neighbour discovery on these platforms to prevent dos attacks?
In ex4200 we can set mac address count and set the action to shutdown the port for X minutes, but i could not find something like this for IPv6 and neighbour discovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAC addresses are used with IPv4 and IPv6 alike. Just the IP→MAC resolution by ARP or NDP differs.